# How do I use a for loop in cmd to get a count of how many subdirs are older than 30 days

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs nightly to erase sub directories that are older than 30 days. This batch file runs just fine but is causing issues with the controller that calls it.

If there are no subdirectories that meet this condition then an error is thrown which is causing the issue.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
FORFILES /P "<path>" /D -30 /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR == TRUE RD /S /Q @path"
```

What I would like to do is loop through the parent folder, count how many sub directories are older than 30 days, if count > 1 I will call the forfiles snippet above.  Can anyone help me out with this?

This is the error out:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9aiT.png)

Comment: `For /f "delims=" %A in ('forfiles /d -30') Do Set /a Count=Count+1)` `%Count%` will contain the number of files and folders or won't exist if none (so do `set count=0` first). `%count%` is only correct AFTER the line has finished running.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. If there is less than `1` directory older than `30` days then `@ISDIR` cannot `==TRUE` and `RD /S /Q @path` won't run

Comment: The error is not generated when the command attempts to remove the directory it sends an error code when it searches with ForFiles and doesn't come back with anything.

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE], then edit your question to include the relevant error message, not a URL to an image.

Comment: @ACatInLove Your `set /a` can be further simplified into `set /a count+=1`. By default, `set /a` substitutes an undefined variable into `0`. Maybe we can change count to `!count!` and enable delayed expansion?

Comment: @SteveFest I'm a basic programmer not a C programmer therefore I code like Basic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  After continuing to research with no simple resolutions to the error code. I decided to give up and use Powershell. Thanks @jwdonahue for the advice.